# Without using Android studio, ant, or gradle, why is a generated .apk file only 15KB, and when installed on phone, app size is 8MB?

Tags: android

I created an android app using butter_paddle (without installing gradle or additional libs and frameworks like dart and flutter), and because of that the resulting .apk file is only 15KB.  After installing the .apk file, the app size is 139KB on emulator and 8MB on phone?

Build Tool I used:
https://github.com/scriptmaster/butter_paddle

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after I set, minSDKVersion to 24, the app installed size in phone is 140KB only.

AndroidManifest.xml:
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" />`